# how to get elements from HTTPIterator

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

here I'm to access the files in a bucket.here file is of type HTTPIterator so for getting files in this is there any other way to access files without for loop

```
def extract_data(buck_name):
  bucket = client.get_bucket(buck_name)
  files = bucket.list_blobs()
  for file in files:
    byte_data = file.download_as_string()
    s = str(byte_data, 'utf-8')
    data = StringIO(s)
    df = pd.read_csv(data)
  return df
```